# C# console best practice for displaying messages from the constructor

Tags: c#, class, constructor, output

So from what I have read/researched and applied in my programs I have not put any output specific methods in my classes. As in it is bad practice to do so.

For example for when creating a method I do this:

```
public string Greeting() {
  return $"Hello {Name}"; //Name is a property of the class
}
```

Instead of doing this:

```
public void Greeting() 
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Hello {Name}"); //Name is a property of the class
}
```

**Question:**

What is the best practice to output a message to the console when a constructor runs and needs to return a message? I want to keep my class portable between different application types.

Do I have to create a `Console.WriteLine()` and just remove that if I move my class to another type of app? That would go against best practice right?

Comment: aren't you looking for some kind of logger? log4net?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of returning / writing the property into Console?

Comment: No I still want the user to see the message - but I want the output of that message to be specified in an object where the class is instantiated. For example the `Main` method in console, but could be something else somewhere else

Comment: I don't understand this sentence:  `but I want the output of that message to be specified in an object where the class is instantiated.`

Comment: I second the first comment.  Just use a logger.  You can redirect the logger output to the console, or wherever else you might want it to appear.

Comment: @amy So I may want to instantiate a class in an event or a method called by an event, but this event or method may not be part of a console application. Say if it is WPF or UWP that does not know of the console class, then the program would not work if the constructor tries to output to the console.

Comment: The most general, but also least capable interface for logging things is the framework's own `Trace`. It has the benefit that every logging framework that's more powerful/capable supports integrating `Trace` logging somehow, so it's a safe choice for reusable code.

Comment: Implement I/O based on interface

Comment: When you ask for best practice, I would assume we are talking about something of a design principle. In this case, the ideal way to handle it is using the pub-sub model. A trace/log can be directed towards any output - console/file/eventlog/database - and the best practice is to separate the creation of the log info from the consumption of it. For instance, just like in WCF, the trace information can be written, and several consumers can be defined, each implementing an interface, and each in turn having the specific behavior - log to event, or log to DB, or log to file. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback :-) I have looked for some loggers and found `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` but this is not compiling in `.net core 2.0` (yes i have add the nuget package) - Could someone please add it into an answer how to set this up?

Comment: @binDebug the idea makes sense, but I lack a bit of sharp in my C# :-) So I will need to play around with the idea.

Comment: Have you considered using [Trace.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.write(v=vs.110).aspx)? That way, the caller can setup whatever kind of listener they want, and it will receive your messages. Check out [Tracing and Instrumenting Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/tracing-and-instrumenting-applications)

Comment: Yeah I will look into that - I know about .Debug one, but not the trace one. So that may work

Comment: This depends on the nature of your "messages".  Are they error messages?  Are they developer info messages?  Are they information the user needs in real time?  For errors, you need error handling and logging.  For developer info, you should just log and utilize the logs for development.  If they are user information messages, use a static class and an environment variable within that class to determine the method of output.  With a static method you can pass the message text, and output, completely independent of your other code, and have it accessible from anywhere you may find a need for it

Comment: @user7396598 I like this answer, this more what I thought would be the right answer. Thank you for the options. To all the others I realise I wasn't clear with what type of message I want in the OP.

Comment: Glad it helped.  I have expanded it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the nature of your "messages".

Are they error messages? Are they developer info messages? Are they information the user needs in real time?

For errors, you need error handling and logging.

For developer info, you should just log and utilize the logs for development.

If they are user information messages, use a static class and an environment variable within that class to determine the method of output.  The simplest implementation I can think of is to set the environment variable in some kind of config file and read it in at application start, and a switch case to determine the output method called.

With a static method you can pass the message text, and then output message, completely independent of your other code, and have it accessible from anywhere you may find a need for it.

"Completely independent" meaning the only requirement is that your static class exist...there is still a dependency but at least you are not using and instantiating a "DisplayMessage" class object in each of your other classes.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your intention.  Are you trying to avoid a dependency to the console?  If so, the caller will need to handle the writing.  In this case you may want to create a separate presentation assembly, which you can then reference in other projects or perhaps more importantly NOT reference in other projects.

If you want your class to support more than one type of output, then you may want to create custom interfaces, as others have mentioned, one for each output type (console, logfile, etc.)

Inheritance is a third option, but I suspect that's not what you want, unless you have a lot of custom implementation related to your output.